# POST request returns none in FLASK REST API

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js, flask

Hi I am currently trying to post to my python flask api.

In the frontend I have the following:

```
function onSubmit() {
  fetch(environment.api + "get-selection", {
    method: "POST",
    header: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(selection.value),
  });
  console.log(selection.value)
}
```

In the backend I am just trying to deal with it like this:

```
@routes.route("/get-selection", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def get_people():
  data = request.get_json()
  # data_json = data["target"]
  print(format(data))

  return "Hello World"
```

I am currently returning that string because otherwise I get the following error

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCbeR.png)

When printing `data` I just get `None`...

I already tried `request.json`and `request.json()`as well as `request.get_json` and nothing worked so far. For the ones asking how `selection.value` looks:

[selection.value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZLM4.png)

I really cannot get my head around that problem and hope one of you might have an answers.

Comment: Please post error messages as text, not pictures.

Comment: And if you check the error message you can see there seems to be a CORS problem. Very common issue raised many times, it would be worth doing a search on that.

Comment: I have tried this one `request.data` and it worked fine